# can't access getters in store module

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, store, vuex

This is the definition of my store module.

```
// rest defined above
const _GETTERS = {
  getName: state => {
    return state.current.name;
  },
  getLastName: state => {
    return state.current.lastName;
  },
  getFullName: (state, getters) => {
    // return `${state.current.name} ${state.current.lastName}`;
    return `${getters.getName()} ${getters.getLastName()}`;
  },
  getMailAddress: state => {
    return state.current.mailAddress;
  }
};

const UsersStore = {
  ...
  getters: _GETTERS
};
```

The above is my `user-store` module and I get a `Uncaught TypeError: getters.getName is not a function` ERROR. When I change the code to use the version which accesses the `state` instead of the `getters`, everything works fine. Below is the main store object where I add the above as a module.

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  strict: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  state: _state,
  getters: _getters,
  actions: _actions,
  mutations: _mutations,
  modules: {
    users: UserStore
  }
});
```

This is where it should be rendered and it works just fine when accessing the store directly instead of using the getters.

```
import {Component, Vue} from 'vue-property-decorator';
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';

const template = require('./app-footer.vue').default;

@Component({
  mixins: [template],
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      name: 'getFullName'
    })
  }
})
export default class AppFooter extends Vue {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem

Here's your error:

> `Uncaught TypeError: getters.getName is not a function`

Here's your code:

> ```
> getFullName: (state, getters) => {
>   return `${getters.getName()} ${getters.getLastName()}`;
> },
> ```

The error is thrown because you are trying to call `getters.getName` as a function (`getters.getName()`) when it is not a function.

You can compare that with the case where you report no error being thrown:

> ```
> getFullName: (state, getters) => {
>   return `${state.current.name} ${state.current.lastName}`;
> },
> ```

You are accessing `state.current.name` as a property – not calling it as a function.

See Vuex's [getter documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html) for guidance on using getters.

## Solution

Stop attempting to call `getters.getName` as a function by removing the unneeded parentheses.

## Notes

**Why is `getters.getName` not a function? It looks like defined it as a function. Look at this example at the docs – `doneTodos` is a function, right?**

> ```
> getters: {
>   doneTodos: state => {
>     return state.todos.filter(todo => todo.done)
>   }
> }
> ```

– https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html

The methods that you define on the `getters` object are set as getters on the store object. **Getters allow you to access dynamically computed values as if they were a property (ie without a function call).**

> Sometimes it is desirable to allow access to a property that returns a dynamically computed value, or you may want to reflect the status of an internal variable without requiring the use of explicit method calls. In JavaScript, this can be accomplished with the use of a getter. It is not possible to simultaneously have a getter bound to a property and have that property actually hold a value, although it is possible to use a getter and a setter in conjunction to create a type of pseudo-property.

– https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

See the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) for how getters are defined and used.

VueJS takes your methods defined on the `getters` object and uses [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to define getters on the store object which in turn lets you access dynamically computed properties. If you are familiar with VueJS's [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties), the behaviour and usage is basically the same.

## Further reading

- [Vuex getter documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html)
- [JavaScript getter documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

Comment: Hm I tested that before but it didn't work for some reason.. Maybe I had another problem back then - you are obviously correct though. 

Then again how is it not a function? When I have an object property referencing an anonymous function I "call" that property like a function all the time..

Comment: @MJB: I've edited my answer to cover the question in your comment.